# Can we build a special subsection of the site to help users who have problems understanding engineering texts?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes when studying engineering books, there is something that we don't understand. So:

1. Would it be useful to build a special subsection for such help requests?
2. Such a subsection could also contain useful information for finding authors (if it's still possible).

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of "useful to find authors" and explain how you feel the site currently does not support this type of question (i.e., questions asking for help understanding something from an engineering text).

Answer (score 4):

You're getting downvoted because the entire site is for explaining things you don't understand. There's a "special subsection" for engineering questions - it's the Engineering Stack Exchange. There's one for physics, electronics, programming, robotics; the list goes on and on. You can find the author by Googling their name. You can ask pretty much any question you want, as long as:

1. It's relevant to the site (engineering questions on Engineering, etc.), and
2. You have a *specific, answerable question based on a problem you actually face*.

That's it. If you can meet those two criteria, ask the question and get an answer. The second point there is important. If you ask something like, "How can I learn engineering?" then it's not a *specific, answerable question*. Hypothetical questions are generally not based on a problem you actually face and are generally off-topic as well.

That said, if your question is about clarifying a concept in a textbook, or a homework problem **that you have attempted yourself, can show the work you did, and can point out the specific problem you're having with it** then those questions are great questions and totally on-topic.

Comment: Is not a good way to discourage partecipation with open mind, downvoting a question in "meta" environment?

Comment: @d.pensopositivo - I agree. I think downvoting in general discourages people from asking questions, on both the regular site and the meta site. Personally, if I think a question is poorly worded, I'll vote to *close* the question and leave feedback for the OP to revise the question - this is how I operate as a mod at [robotics.se]. The only time I downvote anything is if I feel that the poster is being belligerent or intentionally argumentative. *I did not downvote your post here*. I'm just trying to explain why I think *other* people downvoted you.

Comment: @d.pensopositivo Meta questions are different than regular site questions. "up vote" usually means "I agree", "down vote" usually means "I disagree".